# Question about Ligero protocol

Tags: multiparty-computation, snarks

I have a question for those that might be familiar with the ligero protocol: [Ligero](https://acmccs.github.io/papers/p2087-amesA.pdf)

In this protocol to be using an MPC in the head paradigm: [described here](https://web.cs.ucla.edu/%7Erafail/PUBLIC/77.pdf). However, in the description of their zksnark they only use interleaved Reed-Solomon checking, but no MPC.

Why is that? Why do they talk about the MPC model they will be using if there is no MPC anywhere in their protocol? I'm confused...